# "communication complexity" or "communication's complexity"?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please if I need to add 's in the folliwng sentence.

> For decades, researches have asked "What happens when we communicate?" One
>   interpretation, called the transmission model, views communication as message that moves directly  from one person to another, similar to tossing a ball and walking away. But in reality this simplistic model doesn't account for communication('**s**) complexity.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to add -'s because, in that sentence, *complexity* already refers to the "complexity of communication."